# TypeError: Could not parse content as FormData with Remix-run and AWS S3 file upload

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, forms, remix.run

I am currently working on a project where I'm trying to parse FormData and handle file uploads to AWS S3 using Remix-run's `parseMultipartFormData` and a custom upload handler. I've run into a roadblock, however, as I consistently encounter the error: `TypeError: Could not parse content as FormData.` Here is the code I am working with:

```
    export const action = async ({request}: ActionArgs) => {
    const composedUploadHandler = composeUploadHandlers(s3UploadHandler, createMemoryUploadHandler());
    const formData = await parseMultipartFormData(request, composedUploadHandler);
    const project: ProjectFormFields = {} as ProjectFormFields;

    const fileFields = [
        'referencesAttachments',
        'documentsAttachments',
        'artworkAttachments',
        'marketingAttachments',
        'investmentAttachments'
    ];

    fileFields.forEach(fileField => {
        const fileJsons = formData.getAll(fileField);
        const files = fileJsons.map(
            (str) => JSON.parse((str as unknown as string) ?? "{}") as {name: string, fileUrl: string}
        );
        project[fileField] = files.map(file => file.fileUrl);
    });

    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
        if (typeof value === 'string' && !fileFields.includes(key)) {
            project[key] = value;
        }
    });

    try {
        const { result, message, status } = await putProjectForm(project);

        return redirect("/", {
            headers: {
                "Set-Cookie": `message=${message}; Path=/;`,
            },
        });

    } catch(error) {
        console.error('There was an error with the form submission', error);
    }

    return null;

     const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
            const requiredFields = [
                "projectName",
                "blockchain",
                "supply",
                "mintPrice",
                "mintDate",
                "twitterLink",
                "emailContact",
                "description",
                "teamSummary",
                "teamMembers",
                "references",
                "documents",
                "artwork",
                "marketing",
                "allowlist",
                "investment",
            ];
        const newErrors = {...initialErrors};
        let $form = event.currentTarget;
        let formData = new FormData($form);

        requiredFields.forEach(field => {
            if (!projectForm[field as keyof ProjectFormState]) {
                newErrors[field] = true;
            }
        });

        if (Object.values(newErrors).some(value => value)) {
            setErrors(newErrors);
            return;
        }

        // Object.entries(projectForm).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        //     if (value instanceof File) {
        //         formData.append(key, value, value.name);
        //     } else {
        //         formData.set(key, value);
        //     }
        // });
        Object.entries(projectForm).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (value instanceof File) {
                formData.append('files', value as Blob, value.name);
            } else {
                formData.set(key, value);
            }
        });

        submit(formData, {
            method: $form.getAttribute("method") as HTMLFormMethod ?? $form.method,
            action: $form.getAttribute("action") ?? $form.action,
        });
    };

    // Initialize S3 client
const s3 = new S3();

// Define the function to stream the upload to S3
const uploadStreamToS3 = ({ Key, Body, Bucket, ContentType }: AWS.S3.Types.PutObjectRequest) => {
    const pass = new PassThrough();
    return {
        writeStream: pass,
        promise: s3.upload({ Bucket, Key, Body: pass, ContentType }).promise(),
    };
};

export const s3UploadHandler: UploadHandler = async ({ name, filename, data, contentType }) => {
    const fileFields = [
        'referencesAttachments',
        'documentsAttachments',
        'artworkAttachments',
        'marketingAttachments',
        'investmentAttachments'
    ];

    if (!fileFields.includes(name)) {
        return undefined;
    }

    const id = uuidv4();
    const filePath = `${id}/${name}`;

    const bucketName = process.env.PDF_BUCKET_NAME;
    if (!bucketName) {
        console.error("Bucket name not defined in environment variables");
        throw new Error("Bucket name not defined in environment variables");
    }

    // Stream upload file to S3
    const stream = uploadStreamToS3({ Key: filePath, Body: data, Bucket: bucketName, ContentType: contentType });
    await writeAsyncIterableToWritable(data, stream.writeStream);
    const uploadedFile = await stream.promise;

    // Public URL to the file
    const fileUrl = uploadedFile.Location;

    // Return a stringified JSON object
    return JSON.stringify({
        name,
        fileUrl
    });
};

    export const putProjectForm = async (project: ProjectFormState) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const formType = 'project';

    const projectData = {
        id,
        formType,
        ...project
    };

    try {
        await ddb.put({
            TableName: process.env.DYNAMO_TABLE_NAME as string,
            Item: projectData,
        }).promise();

        return { result: 'success', message: 'Data saved successfully', status: 200 };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error('Error saving data');
    }
};
```

The error seems to originate from the line where I call parseMultipartFormData. I've confirmed that the request object being passed to parseMultipartFormData is correct and that the FormData being passed from the frontend is correctly formatted. Additionally, I've made sure to use the 'multipart/form-data' enctype in my form.

Is there something I'm missing that's causing this error? How can I correctly parse the FormData to avoid this issue? I appreciate any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: Have you added any logging inside your S3 handler to see if it is being called properly?

Comment: @Kiliman it doesnt even get into the handler for the logs, I think its failing on parseMultipartFormData when its called in the action. Im assuming its to do with the form data

Comment: Hmm... have you tried this example to see if it works? This will help verify you have everything configured correctly. https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/file-and-s3-upload

Comment: @Kiliman Yes I tried this, but I think from what I found it was an issue with the useSubmit in remix:

I actually found your form demo on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/remix-multipage-form-nhzfy6?file=/app/routes/index.tsx 

And im currently implementing this where theres a submit action on one of the buttons so when a user submits the form it with call parseMultipartFormData :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am having the same problem and just can't find an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by adding encType: "multipart/form-data" to the submit

```
submit(formData, { method: 'post', encType: "multipart/form-data"});
```